# Laravel: Using Storage::move() in Windows doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-storage

I'm trying to move contents from one folder to another using Laravel's Storage::move($source, $dest) method but it's keeps throwing the following exception:

> League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException: File not found at path

The path is correct, i double (and triple) checked it. 
What i noticed is that the Storage::move() is looking for the folder using the wrong directory separator (backslash).
I'm using a Windows environment with WAMP Server to develop my application, this is the path Laravel's using to find the file/folder:

> League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException: File not found at path:
>   **C:/project/storage/app/temp/436826e7-bac6-44fd-a0ac-9e19394d9a88/file_name.png**

Both the $source and $dest variables have the correct path with the correct directory separator:

```
$source = Utils::platformSlashes(storage_path('app/temp/' . $file)); //C:\project\storage\app\temp\436826e7-bac6-44fd-a0ac-9e19394d9a88\file_name.png
$dest = Utils::platformSlashes(storage_path('app/public/' . $file)); //C:\project\storage\app\public\436826e7-bac6-44fd-a0ac-9e19394d9a88\file_name.png
Storage::move($source, $dest);
```

I tried moving the files using vanilla PHP to move the files, and everything worked as expected:

```
rename($source, $dest);
```

What am i doing wrong? How can i solve this issue? (Windows 10 x64, WAMP Server and Laravel 5.6)